# Temporary variables for parameters

Tags: function, parameters, autoit, temporary

In AutoIt, are there temporary variables for received parameters like `%1`, `%2`, `%3`, etc. in Windows cmd batch script? For example, in cmd batch:

```
call :func %var1% %var2%

:func
echo "var1 is %1"
echo "var2 is %2"
goto :eof
```

Comment: as for parameters to functions, user4157124 already answered. As for parameters to the whole script (analogue to `test.bat param1 param2`), there is an array `$CmdLine`. Number or params is in `$CmdLine[0]`, first parameter in `$CmdLine[1]` etc.

Comment: @Stephan Thanks for your comment. I got it. I just remembered about $CmdLine, the autoit's default temporary variables containing parameters only for autoit script file execution, not for autoit functions. Thank you,Stephan:-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> … are there any temporary variables for the received parameters …

As per [Documentation - Keywords - Func...Return...EndFunc](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/keywords/Func.htm):

> The parameters are set by you. You later call the function like any other built-in function.

Example:

```
FunctionName('value1', 'value2')

Func FunctionName($var1, $var2)
    ConsoleWrite('var1 = ' & $var1 & @CRLF & 'var2 = ' & $var2 & @CRLF)
EndFunc
```

Returns:

```
var1 = value1
var2 = value2
```

Comment: Thanks for reply:-) I know autoit functions receive parameters through user set variables in that function. But what I want to know is not the user set variables but if there are any system' default temporary variable or array contain received parameters in Autoit. For example, I found the @numparms a while ago, which contains the number of received vaild parameters, so I guessed about the existence of autoit's temporary variable for received parameters and then left this question here..

Comment: Function parameters are defined with the function. `@NumParams` exist, because you can define optional parameters like `Func FunctionName($param1, $param2="default", $param3=15)`, where just `param1` is mandatory, for the other two there is a default, which you can override or omit.